# Would a black theme app get rejected on the App Store because of iPhone X notch?

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-x

My current app inside the App Store has an black theme option which makes the background black. On iPhone X it will hide the notch.

I am currently updating it for iOS 11, but I was thinking that Apple does not want you to hide the notch.

Does anyone know if my update would get rejected because of this? The black theme is just a secondary option, not the main one.

Comment: It won't get rejected. The notch isn't part of the ui design guide. Apple mostly cares about usability, stability, private api's. So long as you can see the time and the carrier in the status bar, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there aren't obvious way in which the notch is obfuscated, it should be fine.  You may want to go with something a bit brighter than pure black so the user can tell where the notch starts and ends; so as to ensure they have no problem with the gestures.  Otherwise should be no problem.

Cheers!

Comment: +1... but remember that nobody on SO speaks for Apple's App Review, so take anything said here with a grain of salt. Given that, the HIG advice about not hiding the notch can probably be read as "don't explicitly hide the notch" — if your app has an all-black status bar area on other iOS devices, it's presumably just fine for it to continue being black on iPhone X.

Comment: For the curious amongst you, here's a good article posted by Toptal on the subject of dark UI: https://www.toptal.com/designers/ui/dark-ui?utm_campaign=blog_post_dark_ui&utm_medium=email&utm_source=blog_subscribers&utm_campaign=Toptal%20Design%20Blog&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=56723015&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-9HfoZZoV_thdLYp0AbJf4M1MgZc_W1-n2-pruF608fDHHlGfjRQKD5DtDrjY7ribt_z4MgWPbwvqZZiYXGj1ergNdT6w&_hsmi=56723015